# Как происходит конвертация объектов fstream(ifstream/ofstream) в bool

Tags: c++, fstream

Мне не особо понятно, каким образом объекты классов fstream/ofstream/ifstream конвертируются в bool. Все, что я нашел, это то, что конвертация происходит путем каста к void* и при достижении конца файла мы получаем 0(false). Теперь вопросы:как вообще происходит конвертация? Что мы получаем, как результат каста (адрес на что?)? Что мы получаем, если файл не удается открыть? Можно ли выражения if(!file) использовать как полноценный заменитель file.is_open()?
Я так понимаю, что каст проверяет флаги состояния и, если не goobit, то возвращается false.
Пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int main() {
    std::ifstream file("someFile.txt");

    if(!file) {
        std::cout << "It\'s fine\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "End\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/ - т.е. для класса std::ifstream определен `operator bool`. `file.is_open()` это иная операция, т.к. файл может быть открыт, однако фэилбит или бэдбит будет установлен

Comment: Вы сказали про стандарт С++98, в 11 изменилось: true if none of failbit or badbit is set.
false otherwise. Тем не менее, немного не то, что я искал. Я хотел бы узнать, за счет чего проихсодит каст в bool

Comment: @ShamilMukhetdinov за счёт специального оператора каста. Советую почитать например http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ (Implicit conversions with classes)

Comment: @pavel а как он реализован?) За счет чего выбирает перегруженные оператор, что вернуть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел на англоязычном StackOverflow:[вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920457/difference-between-casting-ifstream-to-bool-and-using-ifstreamis-open). is_open() проверяет, открыт ли файл и игнорирует все выставленные флаги и готовность файла к вводу/выводу. Каст к bool, в первую очередь, опирается на флаги. Поэтому, если вы сделаете так `std::ifstream file`, то is_open() выдаст false, а (file) - true.

Дополнено:
Ответ найден [Здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)

Comment: *"Если же открыть пустой файл(именно открыть), то is_open() выдаст true, НО (file) - false"* Как проверяли? У меня на пустом файле оба выдают `true`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вы правы, исправил ответ в целом

Comment: А зачем про `operator void *` и `operator bool` убрали? Вроде полезно было.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat каст в void* перестал использоваться после C++11, поэтому не стоит вводить людей в заблуждение